# Firebase emailVerified variable isn't changing after clicking the confirmation email

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, email-verification

I am using firebase with ReactJS, after creating a user I am sending a confirmation email, after clicking the link, the variable emailVerified remains false no matter what I try.

Here's the code where I create the user and send the email:

```
const createUserWithEmailAndPasswordHandler = async (event, email, password) => {
event.preventDefault();
try{
  const {user} = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  user.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {
    user.reload()
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
generateUserDocument(user, {displayName});

}
catch(error){
  setError('Error Signing up with email and password');
}
}
```

And this is the generateDocument code:

```
export const generateUserDocument = async (user, additionalData) => {


if (!user) return;

  const userRef = firestore.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
  const snapshot = await userRef.get();

  if (!snapshot.exists) {
    const { email,emailVerified, displayName, photoURL } = user;
    try {
      await userRef.set({
        displayName,
        email,
        emailVerified,
        photoURL,
        ...additionalData
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating user document", error);
    }
  }
  return getUserDocument(user.uid);
};
```

Even if I logout and login, refresh the page, it still doesn't change to true.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried to force user to logout/login again? I think that token needs to be updated.

Comment: @radulle I did, the variable in the cloud firestore is still false

Comment: Even when you check in Firebase console?

Comment: @radulle yes, that's what I meant. I do receive a confirmation link, I click on it from my email, I get a message that the email is now activated but the emailVerified variable stays false.

Comment: When you open Firebase web interface and go to manage users, it is unverified even there? Also have you tried to clear site data in the browser, use incognito tab or use other browser to check if token will be refreshed there and have email verified?

Comment: @radulle Yea it's not verified there aswell, and I did try another browser/clearing my site data, still nothing.